# In Mongoose using find Query and sorting the data with multiple conditions and changes in sort data

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
//Code for one condition of sort

var query = SbAggregate.find({
    MemberClassType: memberType,
    CreatedDate: { "$gte": new Date(start), "$lte": new Date(end) }
}).sort({ field1: -1, field2: -1 });

query.exec(function (err, doc) {
    //data
}

//In same method doing another query
var query = SbAggregate.find({
    MemberClassType: memberType,
    CreatedDate: { "$gte": new Date(start), "$lte": new Date(end) }
}).sort({ field2: -1 });

query.exec(function (err, doc) {
    //data
}

//Same method another condition for sort
var query = SbAggregate.find({
    MemberClassType: memberType,
    CreatedDate: { "$gte": new Date(start), "$lte": new Date(end) }
}).sort({ field3: -1 });

query.exec(function (err, doc) {
    //data
}
```

Make condition dynamically set by variable and call on same method                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         with multiple queries in multiple sortin conditions.

Comment: can you specify more what you want to archieve ?

Answer (score 1):

The sort parameter is a simple object, you can build it the way you want. Here's an example:

```
//Code for one condition of sort
var sortParam1 = { };
var sortParam2 = { };
var sortParam3 = { };

if (someCondition) {
    sortParam1 = { field1: -1, field2: -1 }
} else if (someOtherCondition) {
    sortParam2 = { field2: -1 };
} else if (anotherCondition) {
    sortParam3 = { field3: -1 };
}

var query = SbAggregate.find({
    MemberClassType: memberType,
    CreatedDate: { "$gte": new Date(start), "$lte": new Date(end) }
}).sort(sortParam1);

query.exec(function (err, doc) {
    //data
}

//In same method doing another query
var query = SbAggregate.find({
    MemberClassType: memberType,
    CreatedDate: { "$gte": new Date(start), "$lte": new Date(end) }
}).sort(sortParam2);

query.exec(function (err, doc) {
    //data
}

//Same method another condition for sort
var query = SbAggregate.find({
    MemberClassType: memberType,
    CreatedDate: { "$gte": new Date(start), "$lte": new Date(end) }
}).sort(sortParam3);

query.exec(function (err, doc) {
    //data
}
```

Answer (score 0):

are you saying you want something like this?

```
//sortFields is our sort object
//{field1: -1, field2: -1}, {field3"}, etc
function getData(sort) {
  var query = SbAggregate.find({
    MemberClassType: memberType,
    CreatedDate: {
      "$gte": new Date(start),
      "$lte": new Date(end)
    }
  }).sort(sort);

  query.exec(function(err, doc) {
      return doc;
    }
  }
}
```

calling it would look like this

```
getData({field1: -1, field2: -1});
getData({field2: -1});
//etc
```

You can pass in any object and pass it to your find query.